How to programmatically modify Toolbar in React Material UI?
I have several pages that I navigate to using a Material UI Select component.  That component is shared among all the pages.  I have a Toolbar on one of the pages with components specific to that page.  I'd like to programmatically change the state of those components (eg. hidden or disabled) depending on different conditions on the page.
I'd also like to swap out toolbar depending on which page I'm on. Seems like a basic need but the MUI docs don't show how to do it.

Here's some code to further show what I mean.  FoodToolbar component is currently shared on each page.  I want the Box component to be shared on each page, but the tool bar should be programmatically modifyable, or swappable, depending on which page I'm on.
FoodToolbar.js
export default function FoodToolbar() {
  const [foodPage, setFoodPage] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    navigate(`/${value}`);
    setFoodPage(value);
    localStorage.setItem("foodPage",value);
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <><div class='food-select'>
      <Box class='box' sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
        <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 160 }} size="small">
          <InputLabel>Select Food Page</InputLabel>
          <Select class='food-select'
            value={localStorage.getItem("foodPage")}
            label="Select Food Page"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <MenuItem value="branded-foods">Branded Foods</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="whole-foods">Whole Foods</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="my-foods">My Foods</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="meals">Meals</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="nutrients">Nutrients</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
    </div>
    <div class='food-toolbar'>
        <Tooltip title="Add Food">
          <IconButton>
            <IoMdAdd />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip title="Delete">
          <IconButton>
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip title="Copy to My Foods">
          <IconButton>
            <LuMoveRight />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip title="Filter list">
          <IconButton>
            <FilterListIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </div></>
  )
}

Navbar.css sets the look and feel of the Select dropdown, and the toolbar.  The display: flex, flex-direction: row, and float:left puts them on the same row.
Navbar.css
.food-toolbar {
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-left: 180px;
}

.food-select {
  background:white;
  color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float:left;
}

Any suggestions?

Can you [edit] to clarify in greater detail what you want swappable, and where and what you have tried already (see [mcve])? What exactly do you mean by "programmatically modifyable, or swappable, depending on which page I'm on"? Also, the component seems simple enough, why not create separate toolbar components for each page you want a different toolbar on?

I added a picture to clarify.  Creating a minimal reproducible exampe is too difficult.

Do you just want the children of the <div class='food-toolbar'>....</div> to be dynamic?

Yes, or swap it out for a different toolbar that contains new children.  But to do either you would need to know which page your on, and I don't know how to do that either.  Presumably there is some kind of onOpen hook?

How do you organize your "pages"? Are you using any sort of router/routing? Can you include a bit more to your [mcve]?

Is the goal only to hide/show certain components? When you say "swap" do you still mean hide/show or also changing their order?

When I say "swap" I mean swap one toolbar for another, or modify one toolbar by adding/removing buttons, etc. depending on what page I'm on.

I figured out how to swap out a toolbar for another one.  So now instead of one FoodToolbar, there is one for each page.  For example, FoodToolbar becomes BrandedFoodsToolbar, etc.
Each toolbar then has it's own set of icons, buttons, etc. and associated business logic.  Here I just show Icons and buttons, but it could be text fields, checkboxes, search fields, or any other component you usually see in toolbars.
export default function BrandedFoodsToolbar() {

  return (
    <>
    <div class='food-toolbar'>
        <Tooltip title="Add Food">
          <IconButton>
            <IoMdAdd />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip title="Delete">
          <IconButton>
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip title="Copy to My Foods">
          <IconButton>
            <LuMoveRight />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip title="Filter list">
          <IconButton>
            <FilterListIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

The toolbar is inserted into each page, like this:
   export default function BrandedFoods() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Layout>
            <SelectFoodPage class='food-select' selectedPage={'branded-foods'}></SelectFoodPage>
            <BrandedFoodsToolbar class='food-toolbar'></BrandedFoodsToolbar>
               ... the rest of the page
          </Layout>
        </div>
      );
    }

I ran into another problem after that.  Since SelectFoodPage navigates to the selected page, the selected page name no longer shows in the Select header.
To fix that, I passed the page value to the page.  Notice selectedPage={'branded-foods'}
The SelectFoodPage component receives it like this:
export default function SelectFoodPage({selectedPage}) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const page = event.target.value;
    navigate(`/${page}`, {state: {selectedPage: {page}}});
  };

  return (
    <div class='food-select'>
      <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ minWidth: 140 }}>
      <Select
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={selectedPage}
        >
          <MenuItem value="branded-foods" selected>Branded Foods</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="whole-foods">Whole Foods</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="my-foods">My Foods</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="meals">Meals</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="nutrients">Nutrients</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

And the Select title is restored via value={selectedPage}
There's probably a cleaner way to do this in which a separate toolbar for each page would not be needed.  You'd have a single empty toolbar that would be used on every page.  Then you'd pass to it toolbar components and associated function names that would contain the logic.  For example, onAddBtnClick(), or onDeleteBtnClick(), etc.  Each page would then handle that event.
Anyway, that's for another day!
